# Graphical console applications in Emacs

Tags: emacs, console, escape-characters, htop, ansi-term

I am having trouble running [`htop`](http://htop.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=main)  within an `ansi-term` in Emacs 24.2. It looks like some of the control characters are not interpreted correctly.

I thought `ansi-term`  was capable of handling font control characters. Is there a way to have `ansi-term` work with graphical console applications?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.  Without a screenshot, there's not enough information in the question to guess what you were seeing.  By the way, [`TERM=eterm-color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-eterm-color) (some users override `TERM`, which won't work well).

Here is a screenshot to illustrate the *graphic* characters:

[image]

If one sets `TERM` to `xterm` (something frequently done...), you can see it works not as well:

[image]

Without overriding `TERM`, `htop` looks fine:

[image]

but again, setting `TERM=xterm` works not as well:

[image]

Further reading:

- [Why not just use TERM set to "xterm"?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_generic)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried replicating your issue and I don't see the problem.  I was able to run htop in ansi-term mode both in my tty window (using -nw) and in the graphical window.

Comment: Hmm, I am running Emacs 24.2 and while I am able to *run* `htop` within ansi-term, some of the characters are clearly not displayed correctly (e.g. at the top left of the window). I have also tried with `emacs -Q` and the problem persists.

Comment: @user815423426: Does changing the shell emacs uses fix the behavior? When entering emacs' term-mode, my emacs defaults to /bin/bash, and htop looks mangled. If I ask emacs to use /bin/dash, htop displays correctly.